# JavaFX Canvas Efficient Animations

Tags: java, animation, canvas, javafx

I am working with a JavaFX Canvas animating the motion of Shape and Polyline objects over time.
Currently, every frame, the location of X and Y of each Shape or Polyline in a list is edited as required and the object is moved.
This results in about 20-30fps

An earlier approach I have tried simply clears the canvas every frame and redraws each object again. No lists of objects are stored.
this results in 60fps

This second method seems to be a far messier approach yet results in a far better framerate.

Are there any best practices or recommended ways to animate on a JavaFX canvas? Anything clean and recommended yet results in a good framerate?

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I doubt that you are using the canvas in your first example. You cannot move anything on a JavaFX Canvas by just changing the x/y locations of some Shapes. I guess you are talking about the scene graph here. Could you please clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just gave a talk about these issues at the JavaLand conference. It is indeed true that for general animations with path based shapes (like Polyline and Polygon) using the Canvas is currently the fastest standard option. This is due to a bug in JavaFX which can make such animations via the scene graph slow. I have reported this issue and a bug fix is on the way.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178521

In this JIRA issue I refer to hardware versus software rendering but it also affects scene graph versus canvas rendering because the canvas does not seem to be affected by this bug.

Comment: Note that the comments below the bug report suggest a possible workaround: set the system property `prism.cacheshapes` to `false`. You can do this from the command line with the VM argument `-Dprism.cacheshapes=false`. If you want to do this programmatically, you apparently must do so *before* the `Application` class is loaded (I don't know why), which means you need a separate main class with `System.setProperty("prism.cacheshapes", "false");` and then `Application.launch(MyApplicationSubclass.class);`.

Comment: I doubt this is a good idea unless you are doing nothing else than animating shapes. Normally it makes sense to cache shapes.